# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x'}{L})$

Tags: summation

Let $x$ and $x'$ be in the interval $[0,L]$

Compute:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x'}{L}\right)
$$

I remember a lot of time i have done this and if I'm not bat the result is $\delta(x-x')$

I have proved the sum diverges when $x'=x$ but i'm stuck when $x'\neq x$

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this, but I was thinking... take fourier transform of the sum and then invert the transformed sum? With dirac delta functions I find dealing with them in integrals is a lot easier.